# how to write sql to update some field given only one record in the target table

Tags: python, mysql, record

I got a table named `test` in MySQL database.

There are some fields in the `test` table, say, `name`.

However, there is only 0 or 1 record in the table.

When new record , say `name = fox`, comes, I'd like to update the targeted field of the table `test`.

I use python to handle MySQL and my question is how to write the sql.

PS. I try not to use where expression, but failed.

Suppose I've got the connection to the db, like the following:

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host=myhost, ...)
```

Comment: Also, what if there is no record in the table. Can I still use update command or shall use insert instead?

Comment: What do you mean by this `When new record , say name = fox, comes, I'd like to update the targeted field of the table test.` When a new record is coming it will be an insert not an update!

Comment: I mean that a new record is ready and I'd like to update it in the table

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is a query which does the Merge kind of operation on your data. Algorithmically:

```
 When record exists
 do Update
 Else 
 do Insert
```

You can go through this article to get a fair idea on doing things in this situation:

http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/17/3-ways-to-write-upsert-and-merge-queries-in-mysql/

What I personally recommend is the `INSERT.. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

In your scenario, something like

```
INSERT INTO test (name) 
VALUES ('fox')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
name = 'fox';
```

Using this kind of a query you can handle the situation in one single shot.

Comment: Let's put it simple. Forget the insert thing, for I've create one record when creating the table. Hence there is always one record in the table. So, how to write the sql to update some fields of the record with execution speed as high as possible since It's updated a lot. Plz give some examples. Thanks.

Comment: This one-record table factually works as shared variables for two processes to communicate. I used threading before (use locks) but now turn to mysql. This's why I need to update it alot. There are only 4 shared variables in the record, hence I don't think it will cause serious confliction.

Comment: I am not sure about multi threaded MySQL but if you just want a simple update then its `Update test set name = 'fox';`